# Code snippet doesn't show up in IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, ide, code-snippets

I am accustomed to use code snippets in Visual Studio. I just type `cw <Tab> <Tab>` and I get `Console.WriteLine();`. But often that code snippet does not show up in IntelliSense under my cursor. That means IntelliSense will not automaticly fill that code snippet to the code, instead it will fill another keyword, in this case `char`.

btw. I am using VS 2017, I also have VS 2015, there it works normally.

[IntelliSense without `cw`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esh8R.png)

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS so your IntelliSense would load again?

Comment: Now I try it, still nothing.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J for "refresh remote references"

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J didn't help. Where can I find it in menus? Not shortcut.

Comment: Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh remote references

Comment: I don't see "Refresh remote references" there.

Comment: Look for the shortcut, you'll find it

Comment: I really don't see it there, are you using VS 2017? image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTpe.png

Comment: Sorry, it probably differs between types of projects or VS distros. In my MVC ones it shows as an option, but maybe it doesn't in yours. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqTHX.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqTHX.jpg)

Comment: Same problem, I created a new snippet in my snippets folder, and when I go to add it, it says there is already one there.

Comment: Well, the way I solve this problem is.. I have switched to Linux, I use VSCode and .NET Core. :) Fedora recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If snippets don't appear in IntelliSense list in VS 2019, a workaround is to insert the snippet manually:

- `Edit|IntelliSense|Insert Snippet` or
- <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> `Insert Snippet` or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

You're then provided a menu to select between existing snippets, including custom ones.

I had this problem with XAML snippets, which for some reason don't appear normally in the popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Tools -> Options -> IntelliSense -> Snippets Behavior is "Always include snippets" or not.

I solved same problem with check this option in vs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me. I used Resharper instead:

Create a live/surround template | ReSharper
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Creating_a_Live_Template.html